# c++ using enum from another class

Tags: c++, .net, dword

I created a class `Adresy`:

```
class Adresy {
    public:
        static const DWORD hp = 0x947000;
        static const DWORD mp = 0x7B2084;
        static const DWORD cap = 0x97EE94;
        enum Flags
        {
            None = 0,
            Poisoned = 1,
            Burning = 2,
            ProtectedByMagicShield = 16
        };
};
```

When I try to use it in this example:

```
if(( (DWORD) adr.ProtectedByMagicShield & pFlags) == (DWORD) ProtectedByMagicShield){
//...
}
```

it says throws the error: `'ProtectedByMagicShield' : undeclared identifier...`

`pFlags` is a `DWORD`, I'm using C++.NET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(( (DWORD) Adresy::ProtectedByMagicShield & pFlags) == (DWORD) Adresy::ProtectedByMagicShield){
    //...
}
```

You need to use the class name and the scoping token (::) to access the values of the enum.

This is because the enum isn't owned by any particular instance of your class but by the class itself, like the static const members.